# How do I represent set of 8 bit binary numbers using Z2 notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Z2 = {0,1}.
I would like math notation for set S = { 00000000, 00000001, 00000010... 11111111}. In computer science this would be set of 8 bit integers.
Perhaps using Z2 or something else.

Comment: The set is known as $4^2$, where $4$ is the set $\{0,1,2,3\}$, and $2$ is the set $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: I removed the spaces withing the numbers like 0000 0001, that was written for human consumption. In other words the elements are {00000000, 00000001, etc}. The other issues is I know Z2 = {0,1} but you write Set 2 = {0,1}, should not it be Z2?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding a string $i_1 i_2 \dots i_k$ are an ordered list $(i_1, i_2, \dots, i_k)$, this set would be $\mathbb{Z}_2^8$.

More generally, if $A$ is a set and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then
$$A^k = \{ (a_1, a_2, \dots, a_k) \mid a_i \in A \text{ for all } 1 \le i \le k \}$$
is the set of ordered $k$-tuples ($\equiv$ strings of length $k$) of elements of $A$.